# Matlab discontiniuos functions

Tags: matlab

Any simple way to define a discontinuous function (such as f(x)=5 if x>5, f(x)=6x if x<5) and evaluate it in a interval (such as [0 6]).

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
f = @(x) 5*(x>5) + 6*x.*(x<5);
```

as in

```
t = 0:0.001:6;
f = @(x) 5*(x>5) + 6*x.*(x<5);
plot(t,f(t));
```

You may want to change your definition to make sure you define the case when x = 5, to be one of the following:

```
f = @(x) 5*(x>5) + 6*x.*(x<=5);
```

or

```
f = @(x) 5*(x>=5) + 6*x.*(x<5);
```